# C# win form custom control - disable selection box, and use font color for selection indicator

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have a custom control based on the label control. My question is how I disable the selection box around this custom control when a user selects it while in design mode. 
I would like to just change the font color when selected, and then change it back when unselected.

The reason for this is because when you have many labels with small font very close together it makes it hard to see the other labels when you select one of them and the selection box from the one selected obscures the user from seen the other labels that are very close to the one selected.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent it from being selectable at design time. It is considered a component of the form and you will always be able to select it in order to be able to delete it or modify its properties by selecting it.